# Как вставить ресурсы локализации в исполняемую сборку?

Tags: c#, winforms, локализация, ресурсы

Привет, народ! Делаю приложение на windows forms (.NET Framework 4.6). Понадобилось сделать локализацию. Сделал как указано [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.110).aspx). После компиляции появляются папки с наименованиями языков ("ru" и "en"), в которых лежат файлы <ИмяПроекта>.resources.dll. Но мне нужно, чтобы все было в одном исполняемом файле. Если их нет, то язык присутствует только системный. AssemblyResolve не вызывается, поэтому добавить их в ресурсы и подгружать когда надо не получится. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ решить этот вопрос или проще сделать свою локализацию?

Comment: по первому или второму способу делали? второй не должен создавать сопутствующие сборки, если верить документации.

Comment: Для форм по первому, а для строк в сообщениях по второму. Если запускать программу без дополнительных сборок, то судя по внешнему виду, в исполняемую сборку встраивается только файл ресурсов по-умолчанию (один из тех, который по второму способу) и файлы ресурсов по-умолчанию каждой формы (которые по первому способу).

Answer (score 1):

После более внимательного изучения вопроса, оказалось, что пользоваться стандартными средствами глобализации и не использовать сопутствующие сборки не получится, это заложено в модель ресурсов платформы по умолчанию.

Подробности:
[Упаковка и развертывание ресурсов в приложениях для настольных систем](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sb6a8618(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Практическое руководство. Создание локализованной версии файла ресурсов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa992030(v=vs.90).aspx)
[Пошаговое руководство. Локализация форм Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.110).aspx)

В таком случае если не устраивает стандартная модель ресурсов и нужна поддержка разных языков в одной сборке - придется строить что-то свое.

Comment: Есть три дополнительных файла ресурсов: LocalizationStrings.en.resx,LocalizationStrings.ru.resx и LocalizationStrings.resx. В случае, когда сопутствующие сборки находятся в зоне видимости приложения, они подгружаются все и язык меняется как надо. Но если их убрать, то всегда доступен только файл по-умолчанию (в моем случае LocalizationStrings.resx). Почему такое происходит?

Comment: @YOricH потому что ресурсы находятся в этих DLL и если их нет, то и ресурсов нет

Comment: @rdon так это понятно. Но тогда получается, что дополнительные файлы ресурсов не включаются в проект. И выходит либо я что-то не так делаю, либо документация не верна.

Comment: В смысле, в исполняемую сборку не включаются.

Comment: @YOricH это уже нужно смотреть какие ресурсы как и откуда подтягиваете, и по факту разбираться. Скорее всего где-то ошибка в выборе ресурса.

Comment: @rdon В файлах ресурсов только строки. Ради интереса сделал [тестовый проект](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eUpWzSHQ5lSkF0MWpURUh2ak0/view?usp=sharing). В нем одна форма и три таких же файла ресурса, по одной строке в каждом. Как указано в документации, для смены локализации использую Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture. Результат тот же - две dll, без которых используется только ресурс по-умолчанию. Что я делаю не так? Или так и должно быть?

Comment: @YOricH ок, сейчас проверим.

Comment: @YOricH мда, похоже что так и должно быть... https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sb6a8618(v=vs.110).aspx